# Asserting for presence of added objects in Django ManyToMany relation

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have the following model;

```
class Station(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.TextField(default='')
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User,default='')
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='members')
```

Now after the following code;

```
user1 = User.objects.create_user(username="username1",
                                     password="password1")
user1.save()
user2 = User.objects.create_user(username="username2",
                                     password="password2")
user2.save()
user3 = User.objects.create_user(username="username3",
                                     password="password3")
user3.save()
station = Station(name="somename",                            
                  address="someaddress",
                  owner=user1,
)
station.save()

station.members.add(user2,user3)
```

I want to assert that the added users are indeed there as the "members" of "Station"

Someone please tell me how

`assert station.members == [user2,user3]` doesn't fly. station.members actually is `<Station: Station object>.members` instead.

Comment: You are trying to test a Django models and not your own, is it really useful ?

Comment: @Charlesthk :D probably not. May take it as an amusement ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`station.members` is a Manager, i.e. it is the accessor for queries on the related users. You need to actually perform a query: in this case, `station.members.all()`.

Comment: Thank you. Needed just to properly read Django's documentation actually :D.

Comment: Mr.Roseman please check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30237820/making-a-link-pass-a-post-method-in-django :)

Answer (score 0):

A few issues with your code, this is the output in my console:

```
>>> station.members
<django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x110774b10>
```

station.members is a ManyRelatedManager rather than a list of user2 and user3.

station.members.all() will return you a list of user2 and user3, but station.members.all() is a QuerySet instead of a list:

```
>>> type(station.members.all())
<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
```

So doing `assert station.members.all() == [user2, user3]` will never be True.

Comment: No but I can check `assert user2 in station.members.all()` and `assert user3 in station.members.all()`

Comment: @afzal_SH I know you can do that. Just want to point out that '==' will not work. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Actually I needed just to read Django's documentation on ManyToMany relation a little proper. I got the answer doing that just after I posted but by the time I got here Daniel Roseman had the answer :). In case you din notice I was originally trying to do `assert station.members == [user2, user3]` Not even `assert station.members.all() == [user2, user3]` :)

Comment: @afzal_SH  I am fully aware that you are doing station.members == instead of station.members.all() ==.  But, it is quite obvious that you are going to do `assert station.members.all() == [user2, user3]` next. I have no intention to argue with you. As long as you get what you need great.

Comment: @:D Okay! Wasn't really arguing though!