# Making a link pass a POST method in Django

Tags: html, django

I have a view acting differently for GET and POST methods and I have the following template for a page containing 2 links to the corresponding URL

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function getsupport ( selectedtype )
    {
    document.create_station.supporttype.value = selectedtype ;
    document.create_station.submit() ;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1> Hey {{ object.username }}! </h1>
  <p><a href="{% url 'list_create_station' %}">View your stations</a>   </p>
  <form name="create_station" method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="supporttype" />
    <a href="{% url 'list_create_station' %}">Create a new Station</a>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to make the second link pass a POST method instead of GET with help from code at http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/textsubmit.shtml

But the link still passes a GET, verified it using Chromium developer tools.

I am a novice and hence have literally copied the code from the reference. I understand bits and parts so please someone give an answer accordingly. It would be lovely if someone tells me exactly what I am doing wrong here and explain to me what changes exactly I have to make.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code for your form should be:

```
<form name="create_station" method="post" action="{% url 'list_create_station' %}">
    <input type="hidden" name="supporttype" />
    <input type="submit" value="Create a new Station" />
</form>
```

You can find information about the submit button and the action attribute [here](http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_forms.asp).

Basically, you need a `submit` button to submit your form, otherwise the data inside your `input` fields won't be send to the next view. The `action` attribute indicates what view should handle the form. If `action` is blank, your form will be sent to the same view you're using right now, but using the `method` defined in the form.

Comment: Remember you can make the button look like hyperlinks using CSS.

Comment: Also the hidden input is unnecessary so is the JavaScript. I guess there' s some way we can have "a link" actually post. But this is more than enough for me.

Comment: @Filly please check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30243865/django-get-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-pk-error

Answer (score 2):

You can also edit the code to something similar to the one below.

```
<form class="success" id="form-id" action="{% url "formly_dt_page_create" pk=selected_survey.pk %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <a class="nav-link {% if page == selected_page %}active{% endif %}" onclick="document.getElementById('form-id').submit();">Add page</a>
</form>
```

You are supposed to give the form an id so that the action from the link can be directly targeting the form.

For instance from the example above I have given the form an `id` of `id="form-id"` and passed the value to the action `onclick="document.getElementById('form-id').submit();"`.

I do hope that this will help someone.

Comment: Thanks for that. Any clue why when the cursor is over the nav-link it does not display the  hand?

Comment: Ok got it with the href="" and return=False;


<li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link active" onclick="document.getElementById('form-id').submit();return false;">{% trans 'Logout' %}</a></li>

Comment: @Maquisard hope it was of great help.