# Django "get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'" error

Tags: django

I am trying to redirect to a page I intend to implement as an object's homepage after creation of one.

Below is corresponding part of my views.py

```
            new_station_object.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("home_station", 
                                                kwargs={'pk':   new_station_object.id}
            ))

class StationHome(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return HttpResponse("Created :)")
```

and corresponding part of my urls.py;

```
    url(r'^station/(?P<pk>\d+)$', StationHome.as_view(),    name='home_station'),
```

But I get the said error;

```
TypeError at /station/2
get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'
```

Someone please help me out.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

The function is getting one argument more than it is supposed to.
Change it to:

```
def get(self, request, pk):
```

The value of pk will be equal to the pattern that has been matched, and since you've specified that it's going to be a number, the type of pk will be int.

Comment: It is still passed in as a keyword argument, so will be present in **kwargs. Run it in a debugger, and it will be there.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#named-groups You are using the named argument in your URL regular expression (P<argument_name>), which as the docs say is passing it in as keyword arguments. And the error explicitly says "unexpected keyword argument".

Comment: It keeps your code more future proof, if any more arguments get added to the url. Your answer was using a positional argument - which you have now changed in the comment.

Comment: Sure that's correct, now that you have given it a default value, it will treat it as a keyword argument. The answer you posted isn't

Comment: You are passing it in as a keyword argument and trying to retrieve it as a positional argument. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419046/python-normal-arguments-vs-keyword-arguments

Comment: Ok, it does work your way after I checked. I would still saying using kwargs is more maintainable, especially if you are using class based generic views. You can pass **kwargs through to any other methods that may inherit from yours.

Comment: Could you please check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30260201/django-typeerror-user-object-is-not-iterable I have got the answer to the original question but I'm having further troubles. Please go through the comment section of the accepted answer, the only one.

Answer (score 22):

add the kwargs into the method definition:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return HttpResponse("Created :)")
```

Comment: Could you please check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30260201/django-typeerror-user-object-is-not-iterable I have got the answer to the original question but I'm having further troubles. Please go through the comment section of the accepted answer, the only one.

Answer (score -2):

Check that if your views.fun_name is same as the function name in views