# Django KeyError 'pk' POST method

Tags: python, html, django

i have post method in form for sort objects

```
<form method="post" action="{%  url 'package_dashboard' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
    <button  type="submit" name="order_by_title">sortByName</button>
    <button  type="submit" name="order_by_date">sortByDate</button>
</form>
```

my views.py

```
class PackageDashboardView(PackageAccessMixin, ListView):
model = Package
template_name = "packages/dashboard.html"

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Package.objects.all().order_by('title', 'version__name'). \
        select_related('title', 'version').defer('title__metadata', 'validation', 'translations', 'diff_fields')
    if "order_by_date" in self.request.GET:
        queryset = Package.objects.all().order_by('-started', 'version__name'). \
            select_related('title', 'version').defer('title__metadata', 'validation', 'translations', 'diff_fields')
    elif 'order_by_title' in self.request.GET:
        queryset = Package.objects.all().order_by('title', 'version__name'). \
            select_related('title', 'version').defer('title__metadata', 'validation', 'translations', 'diff_fields')
    return queryset
```

my urls.py

```
url(r'^packages/$', packages.PackageDashboardView.as_view(), name="package_dashboard"),
```

the error

> Internal Server Error: /packages/ Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "/home/abdel/Desktop/eclair-packager/eclair_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 41, in inner
>       response = get_response(request)   File "/home/abdel/Desktop/eclair-packager/eclair_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 187, in _get_response
>       response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   File "/home/abdel/Desktop/eclair-packager/eclair_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 185, in _get_response
>       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "/home/abdel/Desktop/eclair-packager/eclair_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py",
>   line 68, in view
>       return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/abdel/Desktop/eclair-packager/packager/permission_mixins.py",
>   line 20, in dispatch
>       return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/abdel/Desktop/eclair-packager/eclair_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py",
>   line 56, in dispatch
>       return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/abdel/Desktop/eclair-packager/eclair_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py",
>   line 88, in dispatch
>       return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/abdel/Desktop/eclair-packager/packager/permission_mixins.py",
>   line 96, in post
>       obj = self.get_package()   File "/home/abdel/Desktop/eclair-packager/packager/permission_mixins.py",
>   line 78, in get_package
>       return get_object_or_404(Package, pk=self.kwargs['pk'], **kwargs) KeyError: 'pk' [26/Dec/2018 11:35:56] "POST /packages/ HTTP/1.1" 500
>   109583

Comment: The error message tells you the problem is happening in permission_mixins.py, which you have not shown.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

you may have some problem assigning pk (primary key) in the view or url section[this may help checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30243865/django-get-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-pk-error)