# Django TypeError 'User' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django

Is it not possible to iterate over User objects using User.objects.all()??
I am trying to do the same but to no avail

I have a form;

```
class AddMemberForm(Form):
    user = forms.ChoiceField(choices=User.objects.all(),
                             initial='Choose a User',
    )
```

And I am trying to render it through a template. Corresponding part of views.py below;

```
class StationHome(View):
    def get(self, request, pk):
        station = Station.objects.get(pk=pk)
        channels = Channel.objects.filter(station=station)
        members = station.members.all()
        form1 = AddMemberForm()
        return render(request, 
                      "home_station.html",
                      {"form1":form1,
                       "station":station,
                       "channels":channels,
                       "members":members,
                   },
                  )
```

Finally the corresponding part of the corresponding template,

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'add_member' station.pk %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form1 }}
</form>
```

But I am unable to access the URL due to this form. I get a `TypeError at` corresponding URL `'User' object is not iterable` error.

Someone please help out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) instead of the simple `ChoiceField`:

```
user = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(),
                              empty_label="(Choose a User)")
```

**UPDATE**: You can change the queryset in the form's constructor.  For example if you want to exclude already added members from the form:

```
class AddMemberForm(Form):
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        station = kwargs.pop('station')
        super(AddMemberForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if station:
            self.fields['user'].queryset = User.objects.exclude(
                                             id__in=station.members.all())
```

And then create the form with the `station` argument:

```
form1 = AddMemberForm(station=station)
```

Comment: I have `post` method of a subclass of Django's `View` class taking the user from the form. And I want the selected user to be added in a ManyToMany relation of a model named Station. `station = Station.objects.get(pk=pk)` `station.members.add(form.cleaned_data['user'])` But this doesn't work. Could you tell me what's wrong? I get `KeyError at /station/2/addmember
'user'` error

Comment: careless me! I had written `form = Form(request.post)` instead of `AddMemberForm(request.post)` :/

Comment: Catavaran could you tell me this; What if I want to be able to change the query set while creating an instance of the form

Comment: `form1 = AddMemberForm()                                                                             form1.user.queryset = station.members.all()` This doesn't seem to work

Comment: Use the form's `fields` attribute: `form1.fields['user'].queryset = ...`.  Also see the update in my answer for another example.

Comment: Please check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30264956/django-attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-model